# Neo4j transaction locking

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, java

I'm using Embedded JavaAPI for my realtime application. While one transaction is locked the database my other ajax call throws error that DB instance has been locked by other process. Most of the time my calls are read-only. So my question is: Is there any method exists in Neo4J JavaAPI so that I can lock my transaction as read-only so that other request can get data from DB.

```js
dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
db= dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
tx = db.beginTx();
```

so at this db.beginTx() can I tell Neo4j that it is a read-only mode or something like that.

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe you can update your question with Exception stacktrace (and message). This will be helpful to spot the issue.

Comment: read only transactions don't take locks, only write transactions do. They type of tx is determined automatically.

Comment: @MichaelHunger what about the case when I have two servlets running for same db and query the DB same time in both servlet. I've above code in both one.

Comment: You should share your database instance globally (e.g. as a singleton, created from a WebContextListener during startup and shut down at shutdown).

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there is no such method. But, in fact - it is not needed.

[Neo4j locking behaviour](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/transactions-locking.html)

Read locks: they are "shared". If one transaction reads data from node, then other transaction can do this also.

Write locks: they are "exclusive". When write lock is taken, all transactions will wait until this lock will be relased and only then proceed further. If another transaction has Read lock on node, then write lock will wait until this node will be "free".

In normal case - you should not receive any errors.

There is possibility to get `DeadlockException` ([more info](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/transactions-deadlocks.html)), but it's rare case. If you don't use your own synchronization methods, then you will not see such exceptions.

**EDIT:**

You should ensure that you have only **one** instance of `GraphDatabaseService` in your application. DB instance is completely threadsafe.

Comment: It throws **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to lock store
[<DB path>], this is usually a result of some other Neo4j kernel running using
the same store.**

Comment: Answer edited. Check that you create DB instance only once.

Comment: You should not run more than one database instance on the same store-files.

Comment: As an aside, you _can get deadlock errors_ calling while setting constraints in a parallel environment.

Comment: Updated link in 2021 https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/transaction-management/#transactions-locking